# Behavior of MOUSE_OVER eventListener in action-script-3

Tags: actionscript-3, mouseover, event-listener

If the mouse is over an object before and while a `MOUSE_OVER` event is registered, does it trigger? I ask this because it appears that it doesn't in my program, and I want to know if this is a universal behavior of all `MOUSE_OVER` events.  Is there a way around this?

I'm gonna avoid giving a code example here, because my program is large and complicated.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The `MOUSE_OVER` event will dispatch whenever the cursor enters the bounds of any interactive `DisplayObject`, such as a `Sprite` or `MovieClip`; this includes any of its children (see `ROLL_OVER` if you wish to ignore children).

As well, the event will dispatch in cases where an object is added to the stage and currently happens to be under the cursor.

It is important to make sure that your event listener has been registered before the Flash Player has dispatched the event -- system events are not queued beyond a single frame, and thus no handlers will be invoked for previous activity.

Comment: Think of it this way: the event was fired when the mouseover occurred; it just wasn't caught. The fact that you register later on doesn't mean a new event gets fired. (You can do a hit test to check if you need to of course.)

Comment: Yes, that makes perfect sense, the MOUSE_OVER event isn't repeatedly dispatched when the mouse is over the object, it just happens once, and the event listener wasn't registered at the time to retrieve it. Well is it possible to make the event re-dispatch? I am a month into actionscript, so I'm a little clueless

Comment: Unfortunately I do not believe there is a "nice" way to do this. You would have to write code that retrieves the position of the cursor and introspects the DisplayList to make a determination. An easy hack might be to remove and immediately add the particular DisplayObject back to the DisplayList after you have registered the event listener, thus forcing a re-dispatch. However, if at all possible, see if you can find a solution that allows you to register the event listener before-hand.

Comment: Colin, the easiest way to not miss mouseover events should be to register for them at startup (or when the display object is created) and simply ignore them until you need them, rather than registering later. And accepting this answer is probably a good idea too ;)